# 'super' outside of function or class - react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, super

Working in react-native, I have a chunk of code I've seen demonstrated in various places (e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)

```
let Vehicle = {
    debug() {
        return 'Vehicle';
    }
};

let Car = {
    debug() {
        return super.debug() + ' is a Car';
    }
};
```

No matter how I instantiate Car, I get the `'super' outside of function or class` error:

```
//set prototype on object
Object.setPrototypeOf(Car, Vehicle);
Car.debug(); //error
//create instance
let c = Object.create(Car);
//set prototype on instance
Object.setPrototypeOf(c, Vehicle);
c.debug(); //error
```

Why is this error being thrown and how can I call `super` with objects?

Comment: Unable to reproduce your problem. Your code works as expected (I tested on FF 50.1.0). Are you able to share what environment you are running this code in?

Comment: react-native, specifically, `index.android.js`.  The IDE is WebStorm on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like setPrototypeOf ***has no compatible in react native*** https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html. And here i don't see babel plugin for *Object.setPrototypeOf* https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/babel-preset/configs/main.js#L16.

Comment: Found a plugin - https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-object-set-prototype-of-to-assign - but I'm confused as to why such a thing as a 'babel plugin' even exists. Perhaps this will help: http://jamesknelson.com/the-six-things-you-need-to-know-about-babel-6/